# Formatting Y Axis with Day, Hour, Minute, and Second on a SSRS Report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

### Background of the problem:

I have this data set that provides me the solution I need for the chart. However, I have been struggling to find a solution for the report to correct produce the answer I need below.

[image: Report Chart]

The y axis is supposed to be something moving beyond the 24 hour time mark per vertical axis legend. The data set calculations are correct on the category groups, but the y axis is giving me a hard time to produce the formatting vertical label axis.

### Query Used for this Report:

```sql
SELECT
  -- Category Group for Chart
  [Vendor_Name]
  -- Date of call
  [Call_Date],
  -- Call Time in Seconds
  [Call_Time],
  -- DATE ADD function that does the conversion to days, hours, minutes, and seconds from Call_Time column beyond the 24 hour period.
  DATEADD(SECOND, Call_Time, '00:00:00') [Call_Time_Test]
FROM Phone_Records
```

### Methods Used:

- Used T-SQL `DATEADD()` function to calculate the day, hour, minute, and hour, but it doesn't give the correct output that I am expecting.
- Had changed the interval to Days but it didn't work for my case.
- Used min and max values for the chart and did nothing for me.

Is there a better way to solve this problem without breaking any of code that I've made into the report so far?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in a datetime to DATEADD, not just a time. With this in mind you can do something like this..

```
declare @t table (CallID int identity (1,1), CallDate DATETIME, CallTime int)

insert into @t (CallDate, CallTime) VALUES 
('2022-08-16 23:50:00', 100),
('2022-08-16 23:50:00', 1000),
('2022-08-17 12:00:00', 1000),
('2022-08-17 13:00:00', 1000)


select 
    * 
    , CallDuration =cast(dateadd(s, CallTime , cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime)) as time)
    from @t
```

It looks a bit messy and there probably is a better way to do it but it does work.

First to do `GetDate()` (any date will do) and cast it to `Date` so it ignores the time, we then cast this to `DateTime` to give use todays date at 00:00:00. Then we add the number of seconds to it and finally cast it back to a time so it chops the date off.

The above give the following results...

[image]

Comment: This answer looks fantastic in T-SQL format, but with one caveat: I think that it should be formatted like Day, Hour, Minute, and Seconds in the report chart in the vertical axis. Something like `86600 = 24:03:20 (01:00:03:20)` Or `118153 = 32:49:13 (01:08:49:13)`